# XSLT: copy few nodes only

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I am new to XSLT, Can you guys please help to write a XSLT syntax:
I need to convert my input Xml to the output I shown below. I need to select the nodes with Id '9' and '1' only.

```
My input XML:
<contacts>
 <contact>
    <id>1234567</id>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    <fields type="array">
        <field id="4" name="Gender">M
        </field>
        <field id="9" name="DOB">10/10/1961
        </field>
        <field id="1" name="Mobile">2132312435
        </field>
        <field id="7" name="E-mail">jon@123.com
        </field>
    </fields>
</contact>
<contact>
    <id>1234567</id>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    <fields type="array">
        <field id="4" name="Gender">M
        </field>
        <field id="9" name="DOB">12/12/1956
        </field>
        <field id="1" name="Mobile">234523452345
        </field>
        <field id="7" name="E-mail">pete@tets.com
        </field>
    </fields>
 </contact>
</contacts>


The output I want:
<contacts>
 <contact>
    <id>1234567</id>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    <fields type="array">
        <field id="9" name="DOB">10/10/1961
        </field>
        <field id="1" name="Mobile">2132312435
        </field>
    </fields>
</contact>
<contact>
    <id>1234567</id>
    <firstname>Pete</firstname>
    <lastname>Kelly</lastname>
    <fields type="array">
        <field id="9" name="DOB">12/12/1956
        </field>
        <field id="1" name="Mobile">234523452345
        </field>
    </fields>
 </contact>
</contacts>
```

basically loop through contact and get id, firstname , lastname and fields with id 9 and 1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, all you need is an identity template and an override template to delete unwanted nodes. More like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- identity template -->

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- If field ID is not equal to 9 and 1, delete it -->
    <xsl:template match="field[@id!=9 and @id!=1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

In your xsl, when looping over the field elements in your field array you can add selection criteria to the selection.

For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="field[@id='9' or @id='1']">
  <!-- do something -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

select="field[@id=9 or @id=1]" basicly means select the field elements matching the condition [@id=9 or @id=1]. The @ refers to an attribute, without the @ you would be looking at an element within the field element.